# Can someone explain if environment variables would work for my use case?

Tags: node.js, angular, environment-variables

I am trying to understand how environment variables work in production once an application has been deployed.

I have both a frontend and backend application. Both of these applications live on the same machine on a server behind a VLAN. Depending on the customer, there are times when certain variables in both applications need to be changed/updated after they have been deployed? I don't want to have to hardcode values, recompile, and then redeploy the app for every customer that needs these changes done.

Would an environment variables file (`.env`) be an acceptable solution for this use case? Looking at it from an app deployment perspective as well as security perspective. If not, can someone share some alternative solutions to my problem?

Again, I dont really know how environment variables files work out of development. I understand that you can reference a `.env` file during development and the file takes care of setting the variables to their correct respective values during compilation time but would a user still be able to change these environment variables after an application has been compiled and is being deployed to a live server?

For example, can I have the `.env` file located in the app directory and have the app still reference the `.env` file?

Comment: I think referencing an .env is only possible during build (not easy either?) I think you’ll need a runtime config. Maybe feature flags are worth investigating?

Comment: Feature flag services are the standard approach for this scenario - either in-house or third party saas

Comment: The [enviroment.ts](https://angular.io/guide/build) it's used when you build the app. See that the only Angular makes is used when build becuase in angular.json, in `fileReplacements` array reemplace one for another. So you should rebuild your app if this change but... why not use a simple .json file in your "assets" folder? Then just use a `httpClient.get('your-json-file')` to get the variables. You can use this in [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) to get early in your app

Comment: You can use a solution like [this](https://medium.com/codex/update-angular-react-environment-dynamically-reading-variables-from-kubernetes-configmaps-ae32b8d4021c)

Comment: @Eliseo that is what we are currently doing. Just wanted to see if there was a better way to do it since assets are public

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, no environments variables would not work for my use case and I will be sticking with my current approach, which is what @Eliseo suggested.